# Генератор списка вида a[i] = a[0] * (i+1)

Tags: python, списки, генераторы

Необходимо создать генератор списка с операциями следующего типа:

```
a = ['a']
a[1] = a[0] * 2
a[2] = a[1] * 3
a[3] = a[2] * 4
```

Должно получится:

```
a = ['a', 'aa', 'aaa', 'aaaa']
```

Comment: Кстати, согласно приведённому коду, результат скорее должен получиться такой: `['a', 'aa', 'aaaaaa', 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa']`, так что задача поставлена противоречиво :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
[i*n for n, i in enumerate(a, start=1)]
```

Comment: Что содержит `a` в данном случае?

Comment: @TigerTV.ru то же, что в тексте вопроса `a = ['a']`

Comment: если так, то результатом вашего выражения будет `['a']`

Comment: @TigerTV.ru хм, точно. Видимо, в 2018-м я подумал, что автору нужно обработать что-нибудь вида `['a', 'a', 'a']`.

Answer (score 1):

Можно так

```py
a = ['a'*i for i in range(1,5)]
print(a)
```

или

```py
from itertools import accumulate, repeat

*a, = accumulate(repeat('a',4))
print(a)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, вы можете помочь сообществу если будете задавать вопросы, или дополнять ответ.

Comment: а многие отвечающие могли бы и улучшить качество своих ответов, дополнив приведённый ими код пояснениями. ориентироваться тут можно на [оценённые высоко ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=[python]%20is%3aa).

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, a как же принцип KISS?

Comment: а точно так же: без объяснений написать, конечно, проще, но вот понять проще — с объяснением.